# Access variable after its assumptions are cleared

Tags: maple

After this

```
restart; about(x); assume(x>0); f:=3*x; x:='x': about(x);
Originally x, renamed x~:
  is assumed to be: RealRange(Open(0),infinity)
              f := 3*x~
x:
  nothing known about this object
```

I can use `indets` to access the variable `x` (looks like it's still `x~` in `f`), for example

```
eval(f,indets(f)[1]=2);
               6
```

but it's not efficient when `f` has many variables. I've tried to access variable `x` (or `x~`) directly, but it didn't work:

```
eval(f,x=2);
eval(f,x~=2);
eval(f,'x'=2);
eval(f,'x~'=2);
eval(f,`x`=2);
eval(f,`x~`=2);
eval(f,cat(x,`~`)=2);
```

since the result in all those cases was `3*x~` (not `6`).
Is there a way to access a specific variable directly (i.e. without using `indets`) after its assumptions are cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way, if utilizing `assume`, without programatically extracting/converting/replacing the assumed names in the previously assigned expression.

You can store the (assumed) name in another variable, and utilize that -- even after unassigning `x`.

Or you can pick off the names (including previously assumed names) from `f` using `indets` -- even after unassigning `x`.

But both of those are awkward, and it gets more cumbersome if there are many such names.

That is one reason why some people prefer to utilize `assuming` instead of the `assume` facility.

You can construct lists/sets/sequences of the relevant assumptions, and then re-utilize those in multiple `assuming` instances. But the global names are otherwise left alone, and your problematic mismatch situation avoided.

Another alternative is to utilize the command `Physics:-assume` instead of `assume`.

Here's an example. Notice that the assumption that `x` is positive still allows some simplification that depend upon it.

```
restart;
Physics:-Assume(x>0);

  {x::(RealRange(Open(0),
                 infinity))}

about(x);

Originally x, renamed x:
  is assumed to be: 
RealRange(Open(0),infinity)

f:=3*x;

       f := 3 x

simplify(sqrt(x^2));

           x

Physics:-Assume('clear'={x});
                           {}

about(x);

x:
  nothing known about this object

eval(f, [x=2]);

           6
```

As for handling the original example utilizing `assume`, and substituting in `f` for the (still present, assumed names), it can be done programmatically to alleviate some awkwardness with, say, a larger set of assumptions.  For example,

```
restart;

# re-usable utility
K:=(e,p)->eval(e,
               eval(map(nm->nm=parse(sprintf("%a",nm)),
                        indets(e,And(name,
                                     satisfies(hasassumptions)))),
                    p)):

assume(x>0, y>0, t<z);

f:=3*x;

         f := 3 x

g:=3*x+y-sin(t);

    g := 3 x + y - sin(t)

x:='x': y:='y': t:='t':

K(f,[x=2]);

          6

K(g,[x=2,y=sqrt(2),t=11]);

        (1/2)          
   6 + 2      - sin(11)
```

Comment: It's really weird that ```indets``` sees that variable and shows its name, but we can't access it by a name (neither ```x```, nor ```x~```). Maybe it's a bug? I think we should be able to get that variable since ```indets``` can extract that variable (if not by a name then by address or something like that since somehow ```indets``` does that).

Comment: I've added a couple more alternatives (though personally I prefer to utilize `assuming`).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about [Physics[Assume](https://fr.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Physics/Assume), that page also explained that ```assume``` does change address, while ```Assume``` doesn't. I do use ```assuming``` often, but was curious what's the problem with ```assume``` and now I have a better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you also wanted technical details of why your original attempt (with `assume`) didn't work, because you hadn't asked "why" in the Question.